# best approach to compare database table with datatable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I have some data loaded from an Excel file. It has a key value that I want to validate from a universe of possible values for those keys from a database table. From what I know, based on the performance, I have two choices: compare in a c# method or compare in a stored procedure on the database Server.

I'm guessing that the database approach is a better choice for performance, but I'm stuck trying to figure out the best (performance-wise) way to pass the C# datatable into the stored procedure. It could be XML, load a temp table with an iteration, or something like that. I'm trying to do this without iterating both tables.

Something like:

```
select postal_code
from postaldata
where not exists (
   select ClientPostalCode
   from PassedXML
)
```

I just want to know if I'm pointing in the right direction or if someone has a better one.

Facts:

- **datatable:** Excel table from clients with postal codes (only meaningful column)
- **database table:** all the postal codes
- **trying to achieve:** list of all the codes in the Excel table not existent in the database table
- SQL Server 2012
- .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way:

Concat the values from the excel row comma separated and query the database f.e.

```
Select postal_code from postaldata where postal_code not in (
    excelvalue1, excelvalue2, excelvalue3, ...
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought about it, but i'm concerned about large sets of data (it could reach 150k codes), asuming 17 char long, I will need a 2500000 long string datatype, and I suspect that will be a problem...